# Printing html field in rml report with its formatting

Tags: odoo

In openerp we have a html field **fields.html()**. And the form contains the html editor and the html code is stored in the database. Is it possible to print the html value in rml report with the formatting (i.e the html has to be rendered and the result has to be printed in the rml report) Kindly suggest me a way. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

RML can't parse HTML tags, but you must create you own parser for all tags.
However, simple tags like bold, italic, ... can be parsed by RML if you add in "openerp\report\render\rml2pdf" at ligne 647:

if isinstance(rc1, unicode):
    rc111 = str(rc1)
    rc111 = unicode(rc111.replace('lg;', '<').replace('gt;', '>'))